# How can we motivate homotopy in homological algebra?

Tags: homological-algebra

I'm writing some notes on homological algebra for some readers which are experienced in algebra (had a course in commutative algebra using categorical notions) but who don't necessarily know algebraic topology. With this in mind, I began to wonder how could we motivate the definition of homotopy between two maps of complexes purely algebraically.

While it is true that homotopy is important because homotopic maps induce the same morphism in cohomology or because the homotopic category is useful for constructing the derived category (and is a useful approximation thereof),  it is not clear to me how someone "inventing" (without all the roots in algebraic topology) homological algebra might arrive at such a formula (the one defining homotopy).

What I have in mind is something in the lines of: "this doesn't really work but this formula (the one defining homotopy) is *precisely* what we need for it to work".

Comment: Perhaps it's not so important to motivate "homotopy" with algebraic topology. An algebraic motivation is, as you said, that we have the "fundamental lemma", which is used a lot afterwards. The wikipedia link is [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamentallemma_der_homologischen_Algebra), unfortunately only in German. "Kettenhomotopie" means "chain homotopy".

Comment: @DietrichBurde that is indeed a nice idea but doesn't really fits the bill since I would like to talk about derived categories (where knowing about homotopy is fundamental) *before* talking about derived functors, where this result really appears.

Comment: Maybe you can start with short exact sequences and talk about the distinction split/non split. A split exact sequence will remain so after applying any additive functor, while a non split exact sequence may not be exact anymore after applying an additive functor. What would be the corresponding notion for a long exact sequence ? This leads to the distinction contractible/quasi-isomorphic to 0. Can we generalize even more to a non necessarily exact complex ? This leads to the distinction homotopic/homologous maps.

Comment: @Roland I would love to see that in more detail. Would you like to write an answer? €Gabriel this is a great question I would have liked to ask in the near future. My best guess would be that it naturally appears if you trace the definition of a homotopy of topological spaces through the nerve and Dold-Kan-correspondence, but I didn’t work that out yet (which is why I didn’t ask this question yet). If this is the case and €Roland’s comment doesn’t work, you might try to offer a tiny glimpse on singular homology. Maybe one can even abbreviate it to homotopy of simplicial sets and Dold-Kan...

Comment: @Gabriel Anyway I would like to remark that I really appreciate you putting so much effort in motivating the definitions having suffered under lots of unmotivated abstract math lately (often with applications promised but not delivered).

Comment: @Roland This sounds interesting. While I agree that it is clear that an additive functor preserves homotopy equivalence (and not necessarily quasi-isomorphisms), do you see how homotopy "is precisely what we need for this to work"? The main problem for me is that the formula defining homotopy is something weird that we accept at first and then we see that it has all these nice properties.

Comment: @PrudiiArca thank you for your nice words. If you would like to see what I'm working on, feel free to take a look at https://gabrielribeiro1707.wixsite.com/projects/notes-of-everything and please leave me a word at the chat if you find that something can be improved or if you find some errors :)

Comment: Another way to motivate the homotopy relation is the following https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/chain+homotopy#RelationToLeft This is closer to the topologist intuition even if we don't say anything about topology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A short exact sequence is a useful presentation when speaking about the relation of an object $B$ with a subobject $A$. Sometimes the short exact sequence
$$0\to A\xrightarrow{i} B\xrightarrow{p} C\to 0$$
splits, and $A$ is now a direct summand of $B$. This is a nice property which is preserved by any additive functor, that is, for any $F$, the sequence
$$0\to F(A)\to F(B)\to F(C)\to 0$$ is exact. On the other hand, if the short exact sequence does not split, then the above sequence is not exact anymore in general.

Split exact sequence is generally defined in term of a section $s:C\to B$. But there are other equivalent conditions. In particular, writing $p:B\to C$, we see that $p(x-sp(x))=0$ so $x-sp(x)\in A$. Thus, the map $id-sp$ factor through the inclusion $i:A\to B$, i.e. can be written $id-sp=ir$ for a so-called retraction $r:B\to A$. Put differently $id=sp+ir$.

Conversely, if $id=sp+ir$ for some maps, then applying $p$ on the left $p=psp+pir=psp+0=psp$. So $(id-ps)p=0$ and since $p$ is onto $id-ps=0$ In other words $s$ is a section of $p$. Dually $r$ is a retraction of $i$.

---

The concept of split exact sequence can be generalized for any long exact sequence
$$...\to A^{k-1}\xrightarrow{d^{k-1}}A^k\xrightarrow{d^k}A^k\to ...$$in several equivalent ways :

1. every short exact sequence we get by splitting the long exact sequence is split.
2. every map $d^k$ induces an isomorphism between a direct summand of $A^k$ onto $\operatorname{im}(d^k)$.
3. There are maps $f^k:A^k\to A^{k-1}$ such that $id_{A^k}=f^{k+1}d^k+d^{k-1}f^k$.

Let us prove these equivalences :

$1.\Rightarrow 2.$ The short exact sequences are $0\to Z^k\xrightarrow{i^k} A^k\xrightarrow{p^k} Z^{k+1}\to 0$ with $Z^k=\ker(d^k)=\operatorname{im}(d^{k-1})$ and the differential is $d^k=i^{k+1}p^k:A^k\to Z^{k+1}\to A^{k+1}$. If this splits, then this means that $A^k=Z^k\oplus Y^k$ for a direct summand $Y^k$ and the differential $d^k$ induces an isomorphism $Y^k\simeq Z^{k+1}$.

$2.\Rightarrow 3.$ Let us write $Y^k$ for the direct summand. Its complement is necessarily $Z^k$ since by hypothesis $Y^k\hookrightarrow A^k/Z^k\simeq Z^{k+1}$ is an isomorphism. Write $f^k:A^k\to Z^k\simeq Y^{k-1}\to A^{k-1}$. Then by construction $d^{k-1}f^k$ is the projection $A^k\to Z^k\to A^k$ and $f^{k+1}d^k$ is the projection $A^k\to Y^k\to A^k$. It follows that $f^{k+1}d^k+d^{k-1}f^k=id_{A^k}$.

$3.\Rightarrow 1.$ Write $s^k=f^{k+1}i^{k+1}:Z^{k+1}\to A^{k+1}\to A^k$. We compute $$i^{k+1}p^ks^k=d^ks^k=d^kf^{k+1}i^{k+1}=(id_{A^{k+1}}-f^{k+2}d^{k+1})i^{k+1}=i^{k+1}-f^{k+2}d^{k+1}i^{k+1}=i^{k+1}$$ (the last equality follows from $d^{k+1}i^{k+1}=0$). Since $i^{k+1}$ is mono, $p^ks^k=id_{Z^{k+1}}$. Hence every short exact sequence splits.

---

The last condition actually implies that the long sequence is exact and is open to generalization : replace $id_{A^k}$ by any morphism $\varphi$ of complexes. If $\varphi^k=f^{k+1}d^k+d^{k-1}f^k$, then $\varphi^k$ induces the zero map in homology. (And if $\varphi^k=id_{A^k}$ then the identity is zero in homology which is only possible if the complex has no homology).

Use substraction, that is replace $id_{A^k}$ by $\varphi^k-\psi^k$ and you have a condition, stable by any additive functor, for two morphisms to induce the same map in homology.

Use composition, that is replace $id_{A^k}$ by $id_{A^k}-\varphi^k\psi^k$ and $id_{B^k}-\psi^k\varphi^k$ and you have a condition for two morphisms of complexes $\varphi, \psi$ to induce isomorphisms (inverse to each other) in homology.

Answer (score 2):

You might find this motivation a bit artificial. It also might serve more as a motivation for strict $n$-categories than for chain homotopies.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category. By Freyd-Mitchell's embedding theorem, we can view $\mathcal{A}$ as a full subcategory of $R$-mod for some ring $R$. Pick $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $A_\ast$ be a chain complex in $\mathcal{A}$ of degree $n,$ i.e. of the form $0\leftarrow A_0\leftarrow \ldots \leftarrow A_n$. The complex $A_\ast$ yields a strict $n$-category. (This can be generalized to non-negatively graded chain complexes, yielding strict $\omega$-categories.) Its $0$-cells are precisely the $0$-chains. For $k\leq n$, the $k$-cells between $(k-1)$-cells $a\rightarrow b$ are those $k$-chains whose boundary is $b-a$. Composition is given by addition of cycles.

In particular, for $n=1$, one obtains a category $\mathcal{C}(A_\ast)$. Let $B_\ast$ be another chain complex in $\mathcal{A}$ of degree $1$. A chain map $f_\ast\colon A_\ast\rightarrow B_\ast$ gives a functor $\mathcal{C}(f_\ast)\colon A_\ast \rightarrow B_\ast$ by defining $\mathcal{C}(f_\ast) (a_0):=f_0(a_0)$ for objects $a_0\in A_0$ and $\mathcal{C}(f_\ast)(a_1):=f_1(a_1)$ for morphisms $a_1 \in A_1$. This indeed gives a functor:

> If $d(a_1)=a_0-a_0'$ holds, then we have $d(f_1(a_1))= f_0(d(a_1))= f_0(a_0-a_0')=f_0(a_0)-f_0(a_0')$. That $\mathcal{C}(f_\ast)$ respects composition is shown similarly. That $\mathcal{C}(f_\ast)$ preserves identities follows from the fact $f_1$ as a group homomorphism preserves zero.

Now, a chain homotopy from a chain map $f_\ast\colon A_\ast\rightarrow B_\ast$ to $g_\ast\colon A_\ast\rightarrow B_\ast$ is precisely a natural transformation $\mathcal{C}(f_\ast)\Rightarrow \mathcal{C}(g_\ast)$.

---

The above example is described as well as generalized in Examples 1.4.7, 1.4.10, 1.4.11 of Leinster's *Higher Operads, Higher Categories*.